# Process jquery variable, cut part of it and then put to codebehind, how?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
      <div class="innerPost"><a href="?id=2" class="category">
            <h3>example</h3>
            <div class="categoryEdit">
                <input>
                <button>
            </div>
       </a></div>
```

Ok, this is kinda hard to explain. Also I'm not sure if my question gives any meaning at all, sorry about that.

The above code is in repeater, when you press on a link, which is called "example". jquery slidesin with the `div "categoryEdit"` and add a to url `?id=2` with hash `#?id=2`... then jquery removes the `#`, then Im ending up with a variable `p` which is equal `?id=2`

I would like somehowly and I hope that it is possible, to transfer that variable into asp.net code behind so that If you write something into input and press on button. It will update in database a row that is equal to give `id` from `p` variable.

And I have no idea how D:

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {

    var newHash = "",

        $el;


    $(".insertPost").delegate(".category", "click", function () {

        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");

        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);



    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
    $(".category").click(function () {
        var p = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        alert(p)
    });
});
```

});

code behind c#

```
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE [categories] SET [category_name] = @category_name WHERE [category_id] = @category_id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_name", val);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_id", p);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            Response.Redirect("panel.aspx");
        }
```

Is it yet possible to somehow extract only the "2" number from `?id=2` and then put it into the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_id", p);`

Answer (score 0):

Your browser can send data to the server with a form submit or by issuing a POST request from your JavaScript.

jQuery has a post() method that may look something like this for you:

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).